# 引数部に「?」と「:」が多用されたコードの意味

Tags: javascript, jquery

jqueryの初心者です。

まことに申し訳ありませんが、下の意味を教えていただけませんか？

```javascript
fields.eq( index + (event.shiftKey ? (index > 0 ? -1 :  0 ) : (index < total ? +1 : total ) ) ).focus();
```

Comment: タイトルには『具体的な問題をまとめた』内容を記載してください。[良い質問をするには?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) `jquery`はタグで示すことができます。(習慣としてコアな技術についてはタグとタイトルで重複させることが多いので、わざわざ削除する必要はないでしょうが。)「初歩的」かどうかは他の読者が判断しますので、タイトルや本文に記載する必要はありません。質問につけるタイトルに「質問」と書く必要もありません。というわけであなたご質問のタイトルは問題内容をまとめた情報が皆無です。本文でも、どこがどうわからないかも記述しないで「意味を教えて」では何を説明すれば良いのかわかりません。『中置の`+`は加算を表す』…レベルから何もかも説明しないといけないんでしょうか。またコード中の`fields`、`index`、`total`が何を表しているかの説明も全くありませんが、これらが何を表すかで大きく意味が変わってきます。「jqueryの初心者です」と言ったあまり意味のない情報は不要ですので、「このコードのどの部分まではわかるが、どの部分がわからない」と言ったことを、コードを解釈するのに十分な情報を付加した上で具体的に記述してください。

Answer (score 6):

質問コメントに書いたように情報が足りませんので、細部が推測にならざるをえないのですが、提示いただいたコードは初心者でなくてもかなりわかりにくいコードなので若干説明を試みたいと思います。

`fields`: 複数のinput要素を束ねたjQueryオブジェクト
`index`: 上記のinput要素の中で、現在フォーカスが当たっているもののインデックス(0〜)番号
`total`: 上記のinput要素のすべての個数
と言うことにしておきます。

3項演算子(`?:`)のネスト、3項演算子を長い式の内側で使うことは、コードを読みにくくするための2大テクニックですが、どちらも使われていますのでかなり読みにくいですね。その部分をif文に置き換えてみると、少し長くなりますがこんな感じになります。

```
            var newFocusedIndex;
            if( event.shiftKey ) {
                //シフトキーが同時に押されていたらこちら
                if( index > 0 ) {
                    //indexを1減らしても大丈夫なら減らす
                    newFocusedIndex = index + (-1);
                } else {
                    //大丈夫じゃないならそのまま
                    newFocusedIndex = index + (0);
                }
            } else {
                if( index < total ) { //`index < total - 1`の誤り?
                    //indexを1増やしても大丈夫(?)なら1増やす
                    newFocusedIndex = index + (+1);
                } else {
                    //大丈夫でないなら、…何をしたいんでしょうね???
                    newFocusedIndex = index + (total); //本当は減らす時と同じ`newFocusedIndex = index + (0);`にしたいのではないの? 
                }
            }
            //fieldsの中のnewFocusedIndex番目の要素にフォーカスを当てる
            fields.eq(newFocusedIndex).focus();
```

(冗長なカッコに囲まれた部分が元のコードで3項演算子のネストによって計算しているところです。)
と言うコードになっています。一部を修正して「タブキーが押された時の処理」として実行してやると、自前でタブによるフォーカス移動を制御できるコードになりますが、`?`を付記した箇所のせいで、何をやりたいのか全くわからないコードになっていますね。

と言うわけで、結局「何をやりたいのか全くわからない」で終わってしまいましたが、『こんなコードが1行で書けちゃったよ、俺ってすげー』的なコードを書くべきか、少しでも他の人が見た時にわかりやすいコードを書くべきか、考えさせてくれるネタにはなりそうです。

Comment: 大変よくわかりました。ありがとうございました。